# How does php cast boolean variables?

Tags: php, variables, types

How does php cast boolean variables?

I was trying to save a boolean value to an array:

```
$result["Users"]["is_login"] = true;
```

but when I use debug the is_login value is blank.
and when I do conditionals like:

```
if($result["Users"]["is_login"])
```

the conditions are always false.

Then i tried doing this:

```
$result["Users"]["is_login"] = "true";
```

and it worked.

It's not much of a big deal but when I'm returning boolean values from functions i still have to convert them to strings.

Comment: Are you serializing, converting to JSON, or similar somewhere in between?  If not, no casting should be involved -- you're storing a value in an array and arrays do not care what type of values they contain. If after setting $result["Users"]["is_login"] = true; you immediately put that in an if condition, that if condition should fire.

Comment: It would help to post everything in between saving the boolean and the if.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there is no cast

the

```
if($result["Users"]["is_login"])
```

should work.
can you try to use `var_dump($result["Users"]["is_login"]);` to make sure the variable has been set properly.

you can check is a variable is set or not by using the `isset` ([manual](http://us.php.net/isset)) function.

Also you can find [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) how PHP evaluate the booleans:

> ```
> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> the boolean FALSE itself
> the integer 0 (zero)
> the float 0.0 (zero)
> the empty string, and the string "0"
> an array with zero elements
> an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).
> ```

Answer (score 0):

No casting happens in your example.
Your problem is likely somewhere else.

Would you mind to share a more complete piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if((bool)$result["Users"]["is_login"] == true)
{
    // do something
}
```

.

And reply to one of your encounter:

> but when I use debug the is_login value is blank. and when I do conditionals like:
>
> ```
> if($result["Users"]["is_login"])
> ```

since your return value is boolean value `true`, in PHP it doesn't have a representation for it, therefore appear as empty (mainwhile, if the value is a boolean `false`, then you'll see a `0`

Comment: Au contraire, when output the boolean `false` will be blank and `true` will be `1`.