# What values are == NULL but not === NULL in PHP?

Tags: php, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Null vs. False vs. 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137487/null-vs-false-vs-0)
>   [How does php cast boolean variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726937/how-does-php-cast-boolean-variables)

I know that some values will return true for `$value == NULL` and not for `$value === NULL` but is there a complete list of these values?

Also, is `isset($value)` equivalent to `$value === NULL` and `empty($value)` equivalent to `$value == NULL`?

Comment: Maybe this will answer you http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: The only time when `$value === NULL` is true, is when `$value = NULL`, or it isn't defined.

Comment: Neither of the Duplicate questions address types other than boolean or integer.  For example array() == NULL vs. array() !== NULL.  I was looking for a more complete list than those provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 1):

`NULL === NULL`

Nothing else does. So if a function returns `NULL` then checking with `===` will return true.

> Also, is isset($value) equivalent to $value === NULL and empty($value) equivalent to $value == NULL?

No, not strictly. Those two are "language constructs" and not functions. They only accept variable names, `isset` accepts multiple parameters, and warnings are relaxed when using unset variables.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the triple equals is to ensure the types match as well.  Using only ==, PHP performs truthy/falsy logic, meaning 0==null, 0=='', null=='' are all true, but 0===null, 0==='', null==='' are all false.

Also, '90210'==90210 is true, but '90210'===90210 is false.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you these readings:

> About **`NULL`**: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php
>   About **`empty()`**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php (you are wrong about it!)
>   About **`isset()`**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

From the offical documentation, they are very explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that evaluates to `FALSE` when converted to a boolean is `== NULL`.

So that would be:

```
  (bool) FALSE
   (int) 0
 (float) 0.0
(string) '' // an empty string
(string) '0'
 (array) array()
 // An object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
 // SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
```

And, obviously, `NULL` itself. But only `NULL` and variables with *no value* are `=== NULL`.

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) may help clarify some things.